# Socket/ServerSocket connection doesn't work between devices on the same network

Tags: java, sockets

Server

```
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(9999,50,InetAddress.getLocalHost());
System.out.println(server.getInetAddress()); //prints 192.168.1.109
Socket client = server.accept();
```

Client

```
Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.109"),9999);
```

It works if I run the client and the server from the computer, but not if I run the client on a mobile device on the same network. I think last time I went around this by having Socket connect to the public IP address, and using port forwarding, but what are some reasons that it doesn't work using the local address? What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: When it did not work on mobile, what is the message (or exception)  you are receiving?

Comment: Good point, i've been having issues with debugging with Android Monitor(maybe that's what my question should be about), and the exception wasn't showing, but its NetworkOnMainThreadException, which seems pretty self-explanatory, and I'll get to fixing it. But I had this exact problem a couple years ago, so I thought it was the same thing. Maybe it is though.

Comment: darn, it works now, *facepalm*

Comment: thanks for the obvious suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps you have a firewall running on the server that is blocking connections to port 9999 from hosts other than localhost?

Comment: no, it actually works fine, once i fixed NetworkOnMainThreadException